# I want to add my Custom Control in Tool Box but dosn't work ,message error="does not contain any components that can be placed in the tool box"

Tags: c#, asp.net

[ToolboxData("<{0}:MyWebControle runat=server></{0}:MyWebControle>")]
public class MyWebControle : CompositeControl
{
TextBox tx;
Panel p;
DropDownList d;
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
tx = new TextBox();
tx.ID = "text1";
tx.Text = "my child textbox controle";
tx.Width = Unit.Pixel(80);
p = new Panel();
p.Width = Unit.Pixel(700);
p.ID = "panel";
d = new DropDownList();
d.ID = "drop1";
d.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);

```
        this.Controls.Add(tx);
        this.Controls.Add(p);
        this.Controls.Add(d);
    }
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        tx.RenderControl(writer);
        p.RenderControl(writer);
        d.RenderControl(writer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the preview of your question first and don't submit it if the formatting is a mess. All you had to do is not chop the leading spaces of the first line like you didn't with the rest.

Comment: Also, a question needs to contain a question, not just some code. the title should be a summary of the issue, not the entire explanation. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a proper question.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please fix the code formatting in your question so others can better understand what you are asking.